# Legal Binding on a Game Based Companion

Tags: copyright

I'm currently writing a companion to the popular game Overwatch, and have realized early into development that I don't want to put time into this and then find out I can't use it for legal reasons.

My program will contain information that is copied from different sites and locations, including Overwatch itself, as well as several websites.  I am fully willing and even eager to include the authors of the information, but I'm worried that Blizzard will try to murder me legally for attempting to use data from their game.

It will not cost anything, and I will not make any money except for donations.  How legal, if at all, is this?

Comment: You cant take Blizzards copy written information in any way with out their approval unless you have licencing that says otherwise.

Comment: @Chad There are, in fact, limited statutory exceptions to the exclusive rights of the copyright owners, meaning there may be MANY ways one can use such materials without a license.  This is probably not one of them, although the copyright owners can certainly choose to ignore fan fiction that technically infringes their rights.

Comment: @Upnorth - The comment should have been assumed to pertain to the question exclusively... I shouldnt have to explain that though...  troll along please.

Comment: I presumed you had no clue, based upon your inability to spell copyright properly, so my comment was intended as a counterpoint for those who might misinterpret your comment as having any truth whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

### This is 0% legal

The information you are copying is Blizzard's IP, definitely copyright and almost certainly containing trade marks. What you are proposing is **not** fair use so: it's illegal.